# Issue only in Android Samsung Version 7 Galaxy S6 Edge

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-crash-reporting

I have faced this issue in android Samsung version 7 galaxy s6 edge.
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'boolean
> android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.isDragAcceleratorActive()'
> on a null object reference
> at android.widget.Editor.updateFloatingToolbarVisibility(Editor.java:1541)
> at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1491)
> at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10012)
> at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10717)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:738)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:559)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1870)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3236)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:521)
> at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10946)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5110)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4962)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4546)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4512)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4702)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4546)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4512)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7000)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6929)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6890)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7110)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7074)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7137)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:632)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: Add more details or logs and the code snippet

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: crash analytics now show exact line

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Firebase crash analytics not tell exact line of error and this issue only reported in Samsung device below 8 version.